# Yii2 pretty Url css link not correct

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I've follow this video tutorial to enable pretty URL.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suIx8nyDBKk

Everything works fine, until I use custom css.

If I'm at homepage, css link is `abc.com/css/main.css`.
But when i go to another page, ex: post/index, the link change to `abc.com/post/css/main.css`. So there is no css there, the page is broken.

Please help me how to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use AppAsset to define your css and js files. Also this is related to not using a "/" before the css url, because you not getting a root directory. If you define a css in layout file and not set to be like "/css/main.css", then every time it will break the style while your go out of your root directory. Here is the example:

```
/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/main.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```